# Pl/pgsql передать список

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Можно ли параметром передать не одно, а несколько значений?

```
select myfunc((123,234,344), var)
```

или условие?

```
select myfunc('where id = 123 and db = 2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Однотипные параметры? Используйте [массив](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html)

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_method(INT[]) RETURNS VOID AS $$ 
       ...
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT my_method(ARRAY[123,234,344])
```

Передать кусок sql в виде текста тоже можно, но из-за этого не получится подставить условие как параметр, только целиком строить запрос, парсить и выполнять, что медленнее подстановки параметра в готовый запрос, который парсится на этапе создания хранимки.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc (
    s_where text
)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    i_id integer;
BEGIN

    EXECUTE 'SELECT id
                FROM tablename
                ' || s_where
        INTO i_id;

    RETURN i_id;

    -- or, RETURNS SETOF, RETURN QUERY EXECUTE ...
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Но, повторюсь, лучше подумать, как без этого обойтись.

Comment: про кусок скл можно подробнее?